# What's the difference between まねをする and ふりをする?

Tags: word-choice, words

What's the difference between まねをする and ふりをする and what would be each one's proper translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まねをする means to mimic someone's movement. ふりをする means to behave as if you are that person, or disguise yourself as that person.

Comment: You could also translate ふりをする as "Pretend" if you were to simplify what user4092 said